# event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false; not working in firefox

Tags: angular, firefox, event-handling, dom-events

I am working with angular and I have component **c-button** where in I have below code:

```
  @HostListener('click', ['$event'], ) preventDefault(): void {

      event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false; //event.preventDefault support for IE
      event.stopPropagation();
  }
```

In parent component I have below code:

```
  <c-button class="button-search" (click)="search()"> SEARCH </c-button>
```

I get error on clicking button:

> ERROR ReferenceError: "event is not defined"

I did not get solution on internet to fix this as per my code.

I cannot pass $event to search function as I have to call this function from component class. so how can I define event?

Need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `preventDefault` method needs to have an `Event` argument to reference in the method.

```js
@HostListener('click', ['$event']) preventDefault(event: Event): void {
    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault(): event.returnValue = false;
    event.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. It is working now.  I was trying to pass it to HostListner. I actually do not understand @HostListener('click, ['$event']) preventDefault(event: Event) syntax. 
preventDefault() looks like function definition but @Hostlistner ('click', ['$event']) combined with preventDefault(), I could not understand. I am more familier with this type of syntax: $("#selectot").on("event", function(e){
}); or document.getElementById('selector').addEventListener("event", function(event) {
});... Thanks!! :)

Comment: The `HostListener` is actually nothing other than the (click) syntax you already have. The first argument is the event it should listen to, the second argument is the arguments that get passed to the function.

So the `@HostListener('click', ['$event]) preventDefault(event)` syntax can be translated as `(click)="preventDefault($event)`.